# Check a list of members to find whether any match a given property (e.g. password)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

My issue lies in this bit of code below.
It functions as expected for null or whitespace issue but after porting my staff member login details over to an SQLite db, I'm now struggling to correctly test if the input is a mismatch to all other known member passes[passcodes].
This was obvs much simpler with passcode vars for each staff member in the code sheet with names in there etc, but rudimemtary and I've written in a way to add new staff to this db and it would be good to know how to correctly qualify they dont exist/ match with the input found in the Entry object entPassword.Text and stored in the variable pass in the "code behind".

Any direction would be great as I feel like I'm missing or have previously miss coded some obvious solution.
below is the code snippet where the code just effectively falls through the implemented `foreach` check, making it tough to follow the breakpoint as it just waits ready for more input [which if is the correct passcode, it logs in absolutely fine ].
Maybe the entire approach is wrong, I dunno:/
here is a [youtube screen recording](https://youtube.com/shorts/1HDvxJApDoM?feature=share) of it too, so you can see the non-functioning issue if you wanted for extra clarity - EDIT: please MUTE the video if you watch it, its got horrible notification bell noises that are recorded badly :)

Code snippet below:

```
private async void BtnLogin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pass = entPassword.Text;

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pass))
    {
        InputError($"Passcode: ?{pass} ? Shows nothing was entered: Entry DENIED!");
    }
    else
    {
        List<Member> members = await App.Db.GetMembersAsync();

        IEnumerable<string> memberPasses = from m in members where m.Pass == pass select m.Pass;

        //the trouble ahead...
        foreach (string p in memberPasses)
        {
            if (pass != p)
            {
                InputError($"Passcode: {pass} was NOT a recognized code");
            }
            else
            {
                IEnumerable<Member> member = from m in members
                                             where m.Pass == p
                                             select m;

                Member mem = (Member)member.FirstOrDefault();
                mem.DateStamp = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
                mem.TimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
                memberDetails = new string($" {mem.Usr} @ {mem.TimeStamp} on {mem.DateStamp}");
                await App.Db.UpdateMemberAsync(mem);
                NextPage();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To clarify, it doesnt fire my modal when an incorrect passcode is entered, I expected the foreach to run on each element stored containing a passcode and if it doesnt match, fire the modal off, else let the member enter as the pass was qualified as being in the database. Apologies for not making that clear @ToolmakerSteve

Comment: You're right there, it wasnt hitting the breakpoint unless i hooked one up to the else clause where this statement 
          IEnumerable<string> memberPasses = from m in members where m.Pass == pass select m.Pass;
seems to cause a hanging issue, Ive taken out the foreach that iterates the memberpasses as it's technically not needed[due to the explicit search for a match in the IEnumerable.
This then led me to remove the first IEnumerable [the code line shown above] as it was pointless without the foreach part now, so I'm left with a validating, but not a user informing, login at the moment

Comment: I guess at this stage to try and coin the real issue: is that I know how to validate a correct passcode here but not quite how to search for any incorrect input beyond any null or whitespace condition at the entry of the conditional- to be fair to this... I implemented it before [as mentioned in original question] but had to make variables tied to the page to qualify against before entering a route to successful login, whereas my attempt here was to deliver the same fucntionality but by checking the data held in the local backend

Comment: So after adding your code body and changing over the obvious few things, the code works as expected now. Thank you @ToolmakerSteve I cant seem to upgrade your comment to an answer, so if your levelled high enough, could you convert and I will of course accept it. Thanks for your responses once again and keeping with me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search a list of members to find out if any match a given property.

Here, "pass" compared to "member.Pass":

```cs
var matchingMembers = (from m in members where m.Pass == pass).ToList();
if (matchingMembers.Count > 0 )
{
    foreach (var member in matchingMembers)
    {
        //...
    }
} else
{
    //..tell user no match for "pass"..
}
```